# Creating RSA signature using node.js and verifying using python

Tags: python, node.js, digital-signature

I'm trying to create a signature in node using this code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var data = 'some data'
var signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
signer.write(data, 'base64');
signer.end();
var signature = signer.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
```

The signature and data are sent to python server.

Now I'm want to verify it using python code:

```
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode  
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

rsakey = RSA.importKey(public_key)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsakey)                     
digest = SHA256.new()                               
digest.update(data)                      
signer.verify(digest, b64decode(signature))
```

The verification fails.
When I use the same language for both sign and verify it works.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and have found this to work:

```
import rsa
rsa.verify(message, signature, public_key)
```